# Disable animations for tests in cloud services (Programmatically?)

Tags: android, animation, testing

Currently we can see that two of the major cloud testing services:

- Amazon AWS Device Farm
- Google Cloud Test Lab

do not support disabling device animations as suggested by espresso developers:
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html#setup-your-test-environment

Amazon actually disables the window-animation but this is not enough as the biggest source of flakyness is the Animator.

Google acknowledged the issue but fixing it will take some time.

In the meantime, how would you disable Animator animations without having access to the device?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Window animations in dev options? If that so, disabling through reflection (maybe?) at `@Before` or `beforeActivityLaunched()` might be worth trying.

Basically, Window scale and animation value is set through global `IWindowManager`. Values in developer options are stored as shared preferences.

I doubt accessing `ServiceManager` or `IWindowManager` will not rise `SecurityException` however you may want to look at [`Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE) and `WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE`. Changing this global settings might require additional permission in your application.

From documentation, toggling `WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE` to `0` will get rid of any window animations:

> Scaling factor for normal window animations. Setting to 0 will disable
>   window animations.